# Ghost nginx server serving files but not visible to uninstall

Tags: nginx, uninstallation, purge

I have removed, purged, dpkg purged, everything I can think of to get rid of an nginx somewhere on the server. I can't find it to get rid of it. all of the above say nginx is not installed. But the server is serving pages.

Earlier, I had done a purge to upgrade nginx to a dotdeb version (I'm on a Ubuntu server) and all my configuration files vanished with it. But the ghost server is serving the sites correctly according to the configuration that no longer exists as files in sites-enabled or sites-available.

I can't stop/start/restart/anything this rogue server, since it "doesn't exist".

"whereis" used to return /etc/nginx /usr/share/nginx and /usr/share/man/man1/nginx.1.gz - even while the uninstalls were showing nginx was not installed. I even deleted all three. The server is *still* serving files.

I'm at the point of believing in possession.

Someone please help. I need to get rid of this server and install another version (though it is good that it is keeping sites online till the mess can be fixed).

Anyone know how to exorcise this one?

Comment: I have checked and double checked and triple checked that the domains are all pointing at the server I'm trying to fix. The faulty nginx install is serving sites sluggishly, relentlessly without anything that can be removed to be found. Nothing is stopping it.

Comment: Ok. Rebooting finally killed the ghost server. `apt-get install nginx-extras` gave some errors (I had deleted stuff indiscriminately in my frustration). They were fixed by running `apt-get install -f` and `apt-get purge nginx*` and `apt-get install nginx-extras` worked smooth as silk after that.

My configuration files were lost, of course, but I had backups, so that wasn't really a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think i know why you were confused, unlike windows linux allows users to delete files even when they are running, so even after deleting nginx, the running server wouldn't have stopped by it self, you should have stopped the server first. though it makes me wonder why the uninstall process didn't stop the server before it uninstalled, did you use `rm` or something ?

Comment: I had uninstalled it as best I remember - apt-get remove nginx*